# I do not wish to upgrade 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

How can I continue to update 12.04 but **not** update to a higher Ubuntu version? In other words, I want to install all updates available for 12.04, without unwittingly installing a version update to 14.04 or one of the development releases.

Comment: Can we assume you mean 'update' and 'not upgrade' to a 'newer release'?

Comment: Apologies .. no it does not read correctly .. UPDATE the current 12.04 version, but not UPGRADE to 14.4.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply run this single command**

```
sudo perl -i -pe 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

That's all **;)**

---

*Example*

My `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` before

```
% cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades                                          
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=normal
```

Replace `Prompt=<any_string>` with `Prompt=never`

```
% sudo perl -i -pe 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

My `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` after

```
% cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades                                         
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=never
```

Comment: And why run all these complicated commands for a simple task that can be done in 2-3 mouse clicks?

Comment: All commands? That's one command. And the command line is always an alternative.

Comment: Brilliant, A.B. JUST what I was looking for, and thank you for all the other comments folks .. :0)

Comment: @JackOuzzie You're welcome. Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: No problem A.B. I am new to this forum so still finding my way about .. thanks again. I am sure I will be back  :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can continue updating 12.04 without upgrading to a new release.

Support of Ubuntu 12.04 is till end of April 2017.

If you are annoyed by the release upgrade option, just go to

System Settings -> Software & Updates and turn off that notification.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are updating.  I use Update Manager, which shows up once per day with any updates.  At the top, it shows the 14.04 upgrade, but I just ignore the button.  At the bottom left is a settings button that allows me to show what updates to post.

I attached an image of the settings I use.

If you have these settings, choosing "Install Updates" doesn't upgrade the system.  It only updates LTS parts and whatever software you have installed.
[image: Update Manager and Settings]